# Dyld Error Message:dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process, likely due to architecture mismatch

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I am building a react native iOS app.I have to submit **simulator build** to facebook in order to review my app (my app isn't live yet).

I am using following commands to generate the simulator build.

`xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator13.2 -workspace Project_Name.xcworkspace -scheme Project_Name`

Once I get **Build Succeeded** message I want to verify the build using command -

`2.ios-sim launch /Users/saket/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_Name-bkjjtovswivrldcaslxqeprbkhxr/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app --devicetypeid iPhone-11`

It then starts simulator but my app crashes on start and I get following error in crash report of the simulator.

```
Crashed Thread:        Unknown
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x9] <unknown>
Dyld Error Message:
  dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process, likely due to architecture mismatch
Binary images description not available
```

Configurations

**Xcode version: 11.3.1**

**Xcode Build version: 11C504**

**Simulator: iPhone 11**

**OS: Mac OS X 10.15.2 (19C57)**

**react-native version: 0.60.5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building for i386 (the '-arch i386').  The iOS 13 runtime only supports 64bit.  You probably want to use '-arch x86_64' when building your project.